# How does one modify the axes in MATLAB's phylogenetic tree tool?

Tags: matlab, plot, properties, dendrogram, phylogeny

I want to display pretty dendrograms for some agglomerative clusters I am generating in Java.  I write the clusters out to a file in Newick format.  Then, I can get a pretty picture that is almost what I want.

```
tr = phytreeread('myfile.tree')
phytreetool(tr)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the X axis is not what I want.  I would prefer to "reverse" the axis, because the iterations of the clustering progress from right to left, e.g. `firstName` and `setFirstName` get clustered in the first iteration.  Does anybody know how I can do that, or at least turn off the X axis labeling?  (What is the default  axis trying to tell me anyway?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to gain access to the handle for the axes in which the dendrogram is plotted. If it's the only figure open, you can use the function [FINDALL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findall.html) like so:

```
phyAxes = findall(0,'Type','axes');
```

Now, what you want to change *isn't* the x-axis direction, since this will reverse the plotted dendrogram as well. You actually want to change just the [labels used for the x-axis tick marks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#XTickLabel). If you want to just turn them off, you can do this:

```
set(phyAxes,'XTick',[]);
```

Now, I'm not sure what the x-axis is meant to tell you. In your example, it appears that each branch point is positioned at an integer value along the x-axis starting at 0 for the left-most branch point (the "root", I guess). The right-most branch containing `firstName` and `setFirstName` is positioned at a value of 21. If you want to change the axis labeling so that the right-most branch is at 0 and the left-most branch is at 21, you can modify the axes as follows:

```
set(phyAxes,'XTick',0:21,'XTickLabel',num2str((21:-1:0).'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you?

```
set(gca,'XDir','reverse')
```

**EDIT**
You may find a lot of interesting [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html). Cheers!

Comment: It looked so promising...  After various failed attempts at getting the right syntax, I managed to change the axis direction using the property editor.  Unfortunately, it reversed both the axis direction *and* the dendrogram itself, so the final effect is just as wrong as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar. I don't know if it is new to Matlab R2021b, but there is now a plot(tree) function which will draw the tree on a regular Matlab figure. After plotting, I identify the largest X value and update the XTickLabels.

```
B = [1 2 ; 3 4];
tree = phytree(B);
h = plot(tree);
ax = h.axes;

xdata = get(findobj(h.axes,'Type','Line'),'XData');
maxdist = max([xdata{:}]);
ax.XTickLabel = num2str(maxdist - str2double(ax.XTickLabel));
```

[Phylogenetic tree with reversed Xtick labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpbig.png)